# How to use variables in label.new() text? V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Instead of displaying static text labels, we may want to make them dynamic and context-dependent.

Answer (score 2):

```
//@version=5
indicator("str.tostring() test")

int x = 5
int y = 6
add = x + y
subtract = y - x

if barstate.islast
    Label = label.new(bar_index, high, text = 
     "X + Y = " + str.tostring(add) +
     "\nY - X = " + str.tostring(subtract))
```

[image: Dynamic LabelText]